# When saving a .qgs file in QGIS, another appears. Is this a backup?

Tags: qgis, file-formats

When saving a project file (.qgs), which when executed is automatically loaded with qgis.bat, there's another .qgs file which appears in the same directory of the original project file, although this one is not loaded with the qgis.bat file:

[image: QGIS project files]

This is just out of curiosity but is the latter designed to be a backup of the original .qgs file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are correct in that it's a type of 'backup' file. This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173151/what-does-the-tilde-at-the-end-of-a-file-name-stand-for) goes into what the tilde means. As stated in user76204's answer:

> If a file is appended with a tilde~, it only means that it is a backup
>   created by a text editor or similar program.

Comment: It **is** a backup file made by QGIS, regardless of the operating system. It is not always identical with the .qgs file, but to the one before the last saving.

Comment: @AndreJ - Thanks buddy, that's good enough for me.