# What's the purpose of .qgs~ files?

Tags: qgis, qgs

When i work on QGIS project (named "pro"), some file with this symbol appears in the workspace folder with the name "pro.qgs~":

[image]

I tried to open it- but with no success.

1. How can i open it and what is the purpose of it?
2. What to do, so this file will not create in the folder?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

pro.qgs~ is a **backup copy** of pro.qgs. See: [When saving a .qgs file in QGIS, another appears. Is this a backup?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146926/when-saving-a-qgs-file-in-qgis-another-appears-is-this-a-backup)

If your project file gets corrupted for any reason, you can simply rename pro.qgs~ to pro.qgs and continue to work from there.

Like the original .qgs file, you can open it with a text editor.

Why would you want to prevent creation of a backup file?

Comment: Is there any way to turn this feature in QGIS 3? None of my projects made with the newest version make a .qgz~ file.