# How to fix corrupted QGIS project file that causes Windows to freeze?

Tags: qgis-2.14

I'm running `QGIS 2.14.9` on Windows 7 SP1. I have a project that contains PostGIS layers from a remote server, as well as some (local) shapefiles that I've been doing some development on in the Python Console. I have reached a point, however, where when I try to open this project the entire computer freezes, requiring a hard reboot. My colleague tried opening the project on their computer and suffered a BSOD.

I can open other projects OK. So would like to try removing layers from this project to see if that fixes loading issues, but how can I do that without opening it in QGIS?

Comment: Don't you have the .qgs~ file?

Comment: Ah. Relevant http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/216193

Comment: Exactly that. =)

Comment: So using the backup file... Project was able to load successfully then computer crashed :/

Comment: Yup. Tried that twice. Computer freezes at different points when project is rendering

Comment: Hmm, that's weird: I never had this kind of problem. Try to create a copy and then, using a text editor, to eliminate any reference to the files you don't need. I don't know if I'm saying something stupid, but I haven't any other idea by now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I opened the `.qgs` file in a text editor and decided to delete the most recently added layer to see if that changed anything. First I identified the layer in the `<layer-tree-group ...>` tag. It was something like

```
<layer-tree-layer expanded="1" checked="Qt::Unchecked" id="2015_am_reliable20161123173120092" name="2015_am_reliable">
  <customproperties/>
</layer-tree-layer>
```

I selected the `id` part `2015_am_reliable20161123173120092` and searched for that in the rest of the document. This id appeared 5 times:

- In the `<layer-tree-group ...>` mentioned above
- In the `<layer_coordinate_transform_info>` list
- In the `<layer-tree-canvas>` list
- In the `<legend>` list as a `<legendlayer>`
- In a `<maplayer>` tag. This one is tricky since it was about 300 lines long, so it was helpful to be able to select the entire tag in an `xml` editor.

After deleting each of these I was able to open the project successfully in QGIS!

Answer (score 6):

This isn't an answer as such, but it might help you find out if the file is genuinely corrupt. The file could be truncated, there might be encoding errors etc.

(Having said that, I can't remember the last time this happened to me - if at all...)

The .QGS file for your project is an XML file. This means it is human readable, and can be opened with other applications - including Web Browsers ;-)

- First, **back up your .qgs and .qgs~ files**.
- Next, create a copy of your .qgs project file.
- Rename the **copy** to have an .xml extension e.g. myproject.xml
- Open this XML file in your browser (probably right click the file, not sure about Windows). Or you can open your browser and use **File > Open File**

I **deliberately corrupted** a QGIS project file by removing parts of a tag, so it's no longer valid XML. If I open it up in the browser (Chrome in this case) I see an error message...

[image]

You might get better results with different browsers.

The reason for renaming the copy of the file to **.xml** is to stop the browser from treating the file as if it was a download. (Browsers don't understand what .qgs files are)

That's probably the easiest way to check that the file is genuinely corrupt (without writing code).

If the file opens and displays correctly, it's something else. If you do get an error, edit and update your question with any message you get.

Comment: excellent suggestion. I am sad to report that the `xml` rendered fine. I will attempt to selectively delete stuff from the file, but I feel like we're in bug-reporting territory

Comment: Deleting the layer worked, see my procedure [below](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/221729/36886). Thanks for your suggestion!